# Why do we need Keycloak permissions/policies/scopes if we want to control access on the backend?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm still not able to understand the purpose of keycloak permissions/scopes/policies if we still validate user per resource based on the role of the user.
I use Spring Boot and all the documentations shows that role must be included in the configuration:

```
...
.antMatchers("/api/account").hasRole("account")
.anyRequest() 
.authenticated();
```

We have configured the above policy in the keycloak but on the backend we again check the user role. Why do we need keycloak policy configuration?

In keycloak, we can create authorization scopes. How can I use that scope to protect my api based on this scopes?

I couldn't find a way to add authorization scopes into JWT token but keycloak provides UMA endpoints to fetch scopes, but would it be correct way to implement?

Comment: please see my updated answer and comment if it doesn't solve your questions.

Comment: If you only want to use RBAC and you are fine with just checking roles in your spring boot backend, what makes you think that you need to configure policies in Keycloak?

Comment: This is a great question. I am struggling to figure out what to use in keycloak in order  to create a basic permissions matrix.

Answer (score 1):

By default, spring-security is based on user "granted authorities" (in spring world, roles are just authorities with `ROLE_` prefix). Spring-boot default configuration for JWT turns scopes into authorities.
**But** you might use SpEL in `@PreAuthorize()` or `@PostAuthrize()` and write security rules involving more than just user authorities. See for instance this expression taken from [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies/blob/main/api/user-proxies-api/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/user_proxies/api/web/UserController.java#L117):

```java
@PreAuthorize("is(#grantingUsername) or hasAuthority('USERS_ADMIN') or onBehalfOf(#grantingUsername).can('PROXIES_EDIT')")
```

It checks user either:

- is "granting user": username retrieved from JWT token equals `grantingUsername` path variable
- is granted with `USER_ADMIN` authority
- was granted with `PROXIES_EDIT` permission by "granting user"

You can write about anything with security SpEL, based on security-context (`Authentication` instance created from access-token JWT) and annotated method parameters or returned value.

OpenID standard only defines how resource-owners **identity** must be presented. It contains nothing specific about **permissions**.

As so, each authorization-server is using its own private-claims for permissions (roles, resource-access, etc.).

By default, Keycloak exposes **realm** roles in `realm_access.roles` claim. You can also add user roles specific to a **client** with `client roles` mapper (in admin console: `clients` -> `some-client` -> `mappers` and then click `Add Builtin` button). This will put client roles in a claim like `resource_access.some-client.roles`. You can also write your own mappers to feed any claim with what you need (I wrote [such a mapper here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies/tree/main/api/proxies-keycloak-mapper)). But all this is very Keycloak specific.

If you already defined user roles (or whatever your security rules are based on) in Keycloak, you should find it in JWT access-tokens (open it in a tool like https://jwt.io to check). If so, all you need to do is replace Spring default `JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter` (which converts scopes to authorities) with a converter extracting authorities from Keycloak specific claims for roles.

You could also use libs I wrote for [spring-boot OpenID resource-servers](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons).

Please refer to [tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) in this repo to get started. [`resource-server_with_oauthentication`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication) can provide you with a resource-server with role based access control in 5 minutes (including security rules unit-tests).

If you want to do something else than role-based access control, you'll have to override more @Beans and spring-security components. You could start with this [advanced tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_specialized_oauthentication) or the `api` module of the [complete application](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies) from which I took security expression above.